# windows loading instead of ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have a windows 8.1 preview (upgraded from 8) on my system.
I have one HDD or 1 TB, with one drive 228 GB for ubuntu.

I downloaded 13.04 (64 bit) from ubuntu's site.
used pendrivelinux to create a bootable usb.
restarted the computer, and booted from USB (from UEFI menu).
selected try ubuntu without install
installed ubuntu
made 4 partitions:- boot, root, home and swap.
all went well and the prompt came asking me to restart the system.
Once i clicked the restart button, windows loaded without asking for any OS choice.

so i restarted the system again went into boot menu, which showed, ubuntu also.
Selected it and pressed enter, again windows loaded.

So i googled a bit and installed easybcd, this is what it said.

```
There are a total of 3 entries listed in the bootloader.

Default: Windows 8.1 Preview
Timeout: 30 seconds
EasyBCD Boot Device: C:\

Entry #1
Name: Ubuntu
BCD ID: {63712191-130f-11e3-bef6-84a6c82584a5}
Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Bootloader Path: \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

Entry #2
Name: EFI USB Device
BCD ID: {0bd5b854-4556-11e2-8925-d4bed9614efa}
Device: Unknown
Bootloader Path: 

Entry #3
Name: Windows 8.1 Preview
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
```

I tried adding a new entry also as told on many sites, but all in vain.

I checked to see if ubuntu is actually installed or not.
So when i tried to reinstall ubuntu, it said that it is already installed.

So what can I do now?

Based upon the suggestion, i installed boot repair.
ran boot repair and selected recommended option in boot repair.
system said that i need to turn off secure boot. and then completed saying that i can restart.
On restart nothing changed with or without the secure boot disabled.
That is no boot menu. straight away going to windows.

So i logged in again via USB installed boot repair again.
ran boot repair in advanced mode, but wit default options checked.
system asks me to run a few commands (3) followed by another command.
then says to restart.

On restart this time the USB loads itself, as if there is no windows or ubuntu installed.
I checked the boot menu and there is no windows or ubuntu.

Current boot info summary is:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6059160/

Currently I have secure boot off, i guess i t is required to be disabled for dual boot.

in advanced boot, the default option selected was sd6 for /boot partition
and sd1 for boot/efi partition

My boot repair screen is different from your's.

Then I went ahead and reinstalled ubuntu (deleted the previous install)
Ubuntu is working fine now.

Now i need to find a way to bring back windows to life.
Please suggest how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Boot from a live Ubuntu USB pendrive or CD
and 
**Install Boot-Repair on ubuntu by following steps**

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

After completing the installation you can launch it from System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu if you use Gnome, or search "boot-repair" in the dash if you use Unity. Then follow the following screenshots:

***Method 1***

- **Click on the advanced options**

[image: Initial screen]

- **Tick the options shown below**

[image: advanced option]

- **Change the tab to Grub Location Tab and Tick The options Shown in the figure**

[image]

**Press Apply and Reboot the system**

***Method 2***

- Select the recommended Boot repair options as shown in the first screenshot

***[Documentation :](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)***

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the instruction. Let me tell you I am one day old with respect to ubuntu.
the 3 lines for installing helped.

As i know nothing so, i went ahead and chose the recommended option.
It asked me to disable the boot secure boot option, i said yes.
It then repaired the boot file. Took backup of the windows boot file. (I guess)
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6056110/ this is the paste link.

I am going to restart the system now to see what happens (without disabling the secure boot).

Please let me know what are the affects of disabling the secure boot.

Thanks & Regards,
Shivam Verma

Comment: Hi, the restart did not work. with or without the secure boot disabled.

Comment: And now i am not able to log into Windows as well. This is a new problem that I have created. Guess both have the same solution.

Comment: Error that i am getting is: Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grub64.efi Failed to load grub failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi failed to load grub checking media [Fail]

Comment: @user189491 Is this what you are getting? http://askubuntu.com/questions/262904/ubuntu-and-windows-8-boot-problems-ssd-uefi

Comment: yes, but that was before. After that i panicked and, ran the boot-repair again, this time with advanced options. My screen were different from yours. So i applied with the default buttons checked. It asked to disable secure boot. Then asked me to run 3 commands, followed by another. Then said that a buggy kernal is detected, do i want to activate. I choose yes. It said that no errors found and that i may restart.

But as i restarted, there is no OS to load. No OS in the boot menu.

Have i corrupted my entire system?

Comment: @user189491 Please Edit the question and add waht you have did and what issues you are now facing

Comment: @user189491 As you have a seperate /boot partition when you did the advanced repair under grub location tab did you select the /boot(/dev/sdaX)[X stands for an integer] partition as the place where to place grub or did you go with the default /dev/sda